# JS Iterate one array and change other while doing it

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to ask is it possible to iterate one array and to change  other while doing it. I ask this because i have this function:

```js
function revealTriangles(arr){
    var result = arr
    for ( var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for ( var j=1; j<=arr[i].length-1;j++){
            if(arr[i+1]!==undefined){
                if (arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j]&&arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j+1]&&arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j-1]){
                  result[i]=arr[i].replace(arr[i][j],'*');
                    result[i+1]=arr[i+1].replace(arr[i+1][j+1],'*').replace(arr[i+1][j-1],'*').replace(arr[i+1][j],'*');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
}
```

I want do this because i want to match one char on one row and delete the same char on the next row same index and -1 and +1 indexes if they are the same as the char. for example arr[0][5] is 'a'. i want to make this and 
arr[1][4], arr[1][5], arr[1][6] all '*'; 
When i use only one array i get the problem that i change first two rows then when i move to the second row and want to change rows 2 and 3 , i have already changed the element in row 2 and i cant match it to element in row 3 because its already different.

Comment: If you really want an *other* array, you should do `result = []`!

Answer (score 0):

You can store in a global variable the future iteration value whether you overwrite it with `*` or not. Then you can access the variable instead of the possibly overwritten value from before.

For multiple variables that can be overwritten during each iteration, it will be necessary to store them in multiple variables obviously.

To be clear, you only need to be storing at a given time, ones that you are accessing that possibly have been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.forEach` with the extra `thisArg` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). For example:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var otherArr = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4];
var resultArr = arr.slice(); // *copy* of arr
var result = document.querySelector('#result');

result.innerHTML = 'resultArr before: '+ resultArr;

arr.forEach(
  function (el, i) { 
    if (i < this.length) {
      var addedVals = this[i] + el;
      result.innerHTML += '<br>action within forEach: ' + 
                          [this[i], el].join(' + ') + 
                          ' = ' + addedVals;
      resultArr[i] = addedVals;
    } 
  }, otherArr // <= [thisArg]
);

result.innerHTML += '<br>resultArr after: ' + resultArr;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```